# PostgreSQL : Raster to Vector Conversion

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to convert a raster file (let's say for e.g : small subset Landsat raster image) to Polygons and store it as a table containing lat, long and pixel value using the below mentioned query :

```
CREATE TABLE
   rast_poly AS
SELECT 
   ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast,1) FROM <raster file>;
```

But Using the above, Im getting the following error:

> ERROR:  column "st_pixelaspolygons" has pseudo-type record SQL state:
>   42P16